# Explicitly Rendering ReCaptcha - Onload Function Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

From the documentation I understood that in order to change the language of the recaptcha I have to render it explicitly.

The problem is, however, that it's not really showing up, and the `onload` is not even called.
When I try to render it automatically it does work.

Here's the code:
**In the HTML head: (I have also tried putting this at the end of the body tag)**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=iw" async defer></script>
```

**In the HTML form:**

```
<div id="recaptcha"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var recaptchaCallback = function() {
  console.log('recaptcha is ready'); // not showing
  grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
    sitekey: 'My Site Key',
    callback: function() {
      console.log('recaptcha callback');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You might want to check your `<script>` tag in your `HEAD` - you can't call the `onload` method like that - it needs to go somewhere else, like in your `<BODY>` tag.

Comment: `recaptchaCallback` gets defined but when does it get called?

Comment: @Raad Thanks for the quick comment, I forgot to mention that I also tried putting the script in the end of the body tag.

Comment: @Alex According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render), the `onload` parameter in the script URL should state the name of the callback function.

Comment: You need to load the `.../recaptcha/api.js` script using the `<SCRIPT>` tag, but call the `recaptchaCallback` function using the `onload` property of the `<BODY>` tag, so it's a 2-part implementation.

Comment: @Raad Do you mean `<body onload="recaptchaCallback">`? If so, why does the documentation say to put it in the URL?

Comment: Check the docs - you need to provide the callback as a query parameter to the script url: `.../recaptcha/api.js?onload=...` - note the `?` not `/`

Comment: @Raad Oops, I copied it wrong here. In my code it's `?`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just copied your code, used my own Site Key and it works.

The code I used is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>ReCaptcha Test</p>

    <div id="recaptcha"></div>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=iw" async defer></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var recaptchaCallback = function () {
        console.log('recaptcha is ready'); // showing
        grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
            sitekey: 'SITE_KEY',
            callback: function () {
                console.log('recaptcha callback');
            }
        });
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Check your code carefully, as just a single character typo can stop things from working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied everything again from your code this time and it still doesn't work. I have checked the site key a lot and reordered the scripts but still nothing.
If there was an error I would have probably gotten an error, but I just get nothing.

Comment: @Gofilord - this sounds like a different issue - e.g. it may be a problem loading the recaptcha scripts from Google. Use your browser's developer mode and check what is happening to the requests in your browser - look for any errors in the console or the network tab.

Comment: It's really weird but I tried it this morning, without changing a single thing, and it worked. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Gofilord - glad you got there in the end!

Comment: @Gofilord one cause of this is when the bandwidth is low. Suppose you've 1MB/s for downloads and you're downloading a file at the same time you're loading the recaptcha it fails sometimes

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that your onload method is defined before the recaptcha script.  Otherwise you will have a race condition where the recaptcha script could be attempting to call your method before it is defined (especially if the recaptcha script is cached).

From the documentation for onload https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

> Note: your onload callback function must be defined before the
>   reCAPTCHA API loads. To ensure there are no race conditions:
>
> - order your scripts with the callback first, and then reCAPTCHA
> - use the async and defer parameters in the script tags

For example:

```
<div id="recaptcha"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var recaptchaCallback = function () {
    console.log('recaptcha is ready'); // not showing
    grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
        sitekey: 'SITE_KEY',
        callback: function () {
            console.log('recaptcha callback');
        }
    });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=iw" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<div id="captcha"></div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaReadycallback&render=explicit' async defer'></script>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Render captcha and set call back function on api.js load finish
function recaptchaReadycallback(){
 grecaptcha.render('captcha', {
    'callback' : recaptchaCheckedCallback,
    'expired-callback': recaptchaExpiredCallback,
    'sitekey': 'YOUR-SITE-KEY'

  });
}

// On expiry do stuff. E.g. show error
function recaptchaExpiredCallback(){
   grecaptcha.reset();
   // Show 'check the bloody box' error
};

// On not a robot confirmation do stuff. E.g. hide error
function recaptchaCheckedCallback(){
   // Hide 'check the bloody box' error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not realise that the second callback is only fired upon submission of the form - whereas the first callback is executed on page load.